# How to update table based on values in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was wondering according to the below schema

How can i keep inventory out-stock values updated according to product Qty values in `orderDetail` table.

for example i have the below sample data

**OrderDetail**

```
Order-id Product-id   Qty
1          1           5
```

**Inventory**

```
 Inventory-id  Date      Product-id  In-stock  Out-stock stock-left 
 1             1/1/2016   1           10        5         5
```

lets say in Order-detail table value of Qty is changed to 1 how can i changed it to 1 also in Inventory table.

**Schema**
[image]

Comment: Probably a database trigger can help with this. Have you considered this option?

Comment: No is there any examples similar to my case thanks

Comment: I think the problem is your design is flawed. There is no reason to store the amount of stock sold in the inventory table. The value can, and should, be calculated using the order information in real time when you need it. Consider how complicated this becomes when you get things returned etc... You need to fix the relational model here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use triggers to propagate the values

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[inventory_update] ON [dbo].[OrderDetail]
    FOR UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN

        UPDATE Inventory
        SET OutStock = inserted.Qty
        FROM inserted
        WHERE Inventory.inventory-id = inserted.inventory-id

    END
```

Comment: As you probably guess the error is `Inventory.inventory-id` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Using an Upsert wold help here

```
MERGE INTO tablename USING table_reference ON (condition)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET column1 = value1 [, column2 = value2 ...]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (column1 [, column2 ...]) VALUES (value1 [, value2 ...]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I would say, calculated members should not be used as an attribute in a table. For Example => **Stock = (Total Quantity) - (Quantity Sold)**. This is should be a **calculated member**, nothing but an **expression in SQL**.

By the way, you can still resolve this problem using UPDATE TRIGGER